# Зацикленная анимация увеличения и уменьшения

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Подскажите как сделать анимацию, которую можно зациклить и при этом чтобы объект изначально находился в уменьшенном состоянии, а потом трансформировался в свой реальный размер. Что-то по типу: `animation: pulse` только в обратную сторону. Спасибо.

Comment: transform: scale(XX < 1) --> transform: scale(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(.85);
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale(.85);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(.85);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Решение svg

- Рисуете круг в SVG

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="border:1px solid gray;">

  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="purple" stroke-width="8"     stroke="gold" >
 </circle> 
  </svg>
```

- Анимируете увеличение радиуса окружности в сторону увеличения и
  уменьшения `values="50;100;50"`

Анимация начинается после клика  `begin="svg1.click"`
При одном повторении анимации -  `repeatCount="1"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="border:1px solid gray;">

  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="purple" stroke-width="8" stroke="gold" >
    <animate attributeName="r"values="50;100;50" dur="2s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
  </circle> 
</svg>
```

- Зацикливание `repeatCount="indefinite"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="border:1px solid gray;">

  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="purple" stroke-width="8" stroke="gold" >
    <animate attributeName="r"values="50;100;50" dur="2s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </circle> 
</svg>
```

- Чтобы сделать паузы в конечных состояниях анимации добавляете повторы
  значений конечных позиций

`values="50;100;100;50;50"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="border:1px solid gray;">

<circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="purple" stroke-width="8" stroke="gold" >
    <animate
   attributeName="r"
   values="50;100;100;50;50"
   dur="2s"
   begin="svg1.click"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </circle> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный урок.